# Is IBAction necessary when interface builder is not used

Tags: ios, interface-builder

Do we still need to use `IBAction` as the type for the touch event handling method even if we programmatically create UI elements (like the toggle button below) without using interface builder? Can we just use `void` instead of `IBAction` for the `onToggle:` method below?

For example, in the `MyUIViewController.m`

```
[[self toggleButton] addTarget:self action:@selector(onToggle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Also in the `MyUIViewController.m`, the `onToggle:` method is written like this:

```
- (IBAction) onToggle:(UIButton *)button {
    // Actions
}
```

Comment: No, it is not - it is used merely as an outlet reference for IB.

Comment: Nope, you don't need to use IBAction in this case.

Comment: To @rokjarc, So I can use `- (void) onToggle:(UIButton *)button {}`?

Comment: Yes, you can use that.

Comment: `IBOutlet` is just a precompiler macro that is defined as "void". So it just works as a declarative way to tell things to Interface Builder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `IBAction` is Interface Builder Action, so if you don't use Interface Builder you don't have to use it.

use this instead

```
- (void) onToggle:(UIButton *)button {
    // Actions
}
```

Comment: However sometimes `IBAction` would help to understand code (faster understanding that this method is called after user action). But as long as your code is clean and can be easily understood...